# Android Studios breakiterator, to break text using only space

Tags: java, android, iterator, break

[My code to break the word up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHF4o.png)

Selecting words to change them and so on

Take this for example "make-their-vocal" the code up there break it as "make-"

i dont want that i want the entire "make-their-vocal" so when a change is made i can still remember the change made in memory later and compare.

so basically any way to use break iterator or code up to break by space only?

code here too

TextView definitionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_MainText);

```
    definitionView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    definitionView.setText(definition, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable spans = (Spannable) definitionView.getText();

    BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getLineInstance(Locale.UK); // change this if you want word or what ever
    iterator.setText(definition);
   int start = iterator.first();


    for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator
            .next()) {

        String possibleWord = definition.substring(start, end);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0)) ||checkPun(possibleWord.charAt(0)) ||checkSpace(possibleWord.charAt(0))) {
            ClickableSpan clickSpan = getClickableSpan(possibleWord);
            spans.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            //Log.d("ClickableSpan", "init: " + start +" "+ end);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or links to images, as images are not searchable and this makes it hard to understand your question once the image target gets removed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its bad but it works

List listForStart;
List listForEnd;

TextView definitionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_MainText);

```
    definitionView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    definitionView.setText(definition, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable spans = (Spannable) definitionView.getText();


    String T = definitionView.getText().toString();
    listForStart = new ArrayList<String>();
    listForEnd = new ArrayList<String>();

    int testStart = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<T.length();i++){ //getting the list completed
        if(T.charAt(i)==' '){ //found a space //go backwards unti
           listForStart.add(Integer.toString(testStart));
           listForEnd.add(Integer.toString(i));

            //Log.d("TEST", "init: "+testStart+" "+i);
           if(i+1 <T.length()){
               testStart = i+1;
           }else{break;}

        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i != listForStart.size();i++){

        int start = Integer.valueOf(listForStart.get(i));
        int end = Integer.valueOf(listForEnd.get(i));
        String possibleWord = definition.substring(start,end);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0)) ||checkPun(possibleWord.charAt(0)) ||checkSpace(possibleWord.charAt(0))) {
            ClickableSpan clickSpan = getClickableSpan(possibleWord);
            spans.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            //Log.d("ClickableSpan", "init: " + start +" "+ end);
        }

    }
```

}